# Return text after "_" in string

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know why this isn't working. I'm sure there's easier ways to do this but I have chart names like "Projects_John" and I want to get the `names` i.e. `John`

In the follow example chart_sel is a string that equals "Projects_John".

`MsgBox Right(chartsel, Len(chart_sel) - InStr(1, chart_sel, "_"))`

Comment: What is the error you are getting, and if you correct `chartsel` to `chart_sel` in your `Right` statement, does that fix it?

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that underscore. So that definitely was my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s As String

    s = "Projects_John"
    MsgBox Split(s, "_")(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Technically TheGuyThatDoesn'tKnowMuch answered my question but I'm definitely going to take this approach though, thanks

Comment: I didn't submit as an answer though, and this solution is much better ;)